# How to keep generic type of nested generics with class tokens

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, nested-generics

The standard way in Java to work around type erasure is to pass a class token into the constructor. For example we could define a generic property class like this:

```
class Prop<T> {
    public Prop(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    Class<T> type;
    T t;
}

class IntProp extends Prop<Integer> {
    public IntProp() {
        super(Integer.class);
    }
}
```

But what if I now want to use another generic type argument, such as a list and also keep its generics type. I would have liked to do this:

```
class ListProp<J> extends Prop<ArrayList<J>> {
    Class<J> subtype;
    public ListProp(Class<J> type) {
        super(ArrayList<J>.class);
        subtype = type;
    }
}

class IntListProp extends ListProp<Integer> {
    public IntListProp() {
        super(Integer.class);
    }
}
```

But of course `super(ArrayList<J>.class)` does not compile, neither does `super(ArrayList.class)` . What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generics kung fu you need to make your `ListProp` class compile is this line:

```
super((Class<List<T>>)(Class<?>)List.class); // compiles
```

Attempting to cast directly from `List.class` to `Class<List<T>>`:

```
super((Class<List<T>>)List.class); //compile error
```

results in a compile error:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.Class' to 'java.lang.Class>

But if you *first* cast to typed class `Class<?>`, albeit an unknown type, you *can* then cast it the desired typed class.

The full compilable `ListProp` class is then.

```
class ListProp<T> extends Prop<List<T>> {
    Class<T> subtype;
    public ListProp(Class<T> type) {
        super((Class<List<T>>)(Class<?>)List.class); // magic double cast
        subtype = type;
    }
}
```

---

Something else you may consider, in case you need special code for creating/returning a list, is a typed getter for `t` on `Prop`:

```
public T getT() {
    return t;
}
```

which you can then covariantly override in `ListProp` to return a `List<T>`

```
@Override
public List<T> getT() {
    return Arrays.asList(subtype.newInstance()); // or whatever
}
```

---

It should be noted that you only need the class token if your implementation uses the class, which is not shown in your example code. If you don't actually use the class token, you can let type inference do the typing for you.

Comment: Yes, the getter and code which requires the type token I have, I was just not showing it for simplicity. Wow, that double cast is really some generics kung-fu, but it works perfectly. Kudos for coming up with this solution!

Answer (score 0):

### Small Intro

I know one way you can workaround the problem. Type erasure works to erase types after when compiling since they are not needed to run. This is probably why you can't just access the class List with type. List in itself uses generics and so it would not make sense, or possible, to provide a class for that since in your case T is actually the type of the list elements. The class is actually ArrayList. What you are looking for is the type of collection you are using and the type of element you are using. I've changed your code a bit so that you can accept a constructor for both types.

---

1. T is now the type of the elements in the collection
2. J is now the Collection type

---

### Code

```
  class ListProp<T, J> extends Prop<T, J> {
            Class<T> subtype;
            Class<J> subtypeElementList:

            public ListProp(Class<T> typeElement, Class<J> typeList) {
                super(typeElement, typeList);
                subtype = typeElement;
                subtypeElementList = typeList;
            }

        }

        class IntListProp extends ListProp<Integer, ArrayList> {
            public IntListProp() {
                super(Integer.class, ArrayList.class);
            }
        }

        class Prop<T, J> {
            // TODO: Maybe here the elements again? Depends on what you want to do...
            //
            // or maybe just use the integer as you had previously.
            public Prop(Class<T> integerClass, Class<J> arrayListClass) {

            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that now Prop needs 2 generics arguments even if it only is used with a non generic type such as the IntProp in my example. I don't want to leak the generic type argument of the List into Prop.

Comment: I know that, but I have a feeling that what you want it's just not that straightforward. Just because the class for your example is ArrayList. ArrayList<T> is not a class. It's just a generic type. So to best of my knowledge, maybe an alternative could be to encapsulate both parameters into just one and pass that to the Prop constructor, that is, if having only one parameter is what you are looking for here.

Comment: Even with the encapsulated type it would change the way how prop works, while I want that the nested type J to only touch ListProp. The odd thing is, super(ArrayList.class)  makes perfect sense for run time, because super(ArrayList<J>.class) will have been type erased to ArrayList.class anyway. It's just that the compiler here comes between me and the bytecode so I suspect that there is a way to do this.

Comment: Something that crossed my mind just now is that you could just pass T to Prop. You already know that it's an ArrayList I think, so it might not be necessary to have J in prop, and then you only have one type going in. Would that be a way to solve this?