# How to Prevent Element<Integer> to become Element<Object>

Tags: java, android, generics, types

For Syncing with some pice of Hardware, I have create a Datamodel containing a generic Class
DataField to store different Types of Objects in a HashMap.
HashMap myDictionary.

Now found out that if I store, a DataField into an DataField, it is possible to save an String inside the DataField.
Is there any way to prevent this from happening.

Here is my Code:

```
public class DataField<T> implements IDataField<T> {
    //region Fields
    private T _value;
    private boolean _hasChanged;
    private ChildObserable<T> _hasChangedObserverable;
    //endregion

    //region Methodes
    public DataField(T val) throws IllegalValueException {
        if(val.getClass() != _value.getClass()) throw new IllegalValueException();
        _value =val;
        _hasChanged=false;
        _hasChangedObserverable=new ChildObserable<>();
    }
    public DataField(T val,Observer observer){
        _value =val;
        _hasChanged=false;
        _hasChangedObserverable=new ChildObserable<>();
        addChangeObserver(observer);
    }
    //region getters
    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return _value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasBeChanged() {
        return _hasChanged;
    }
    //endregion
    //region setters
    @Override
    public void setValue(T value) throws IllegalValueException {
        if(value.getClass()!= _value.getClass()) throw new IllegalValueException();
        if(value!=_value) {
            _value = value;
            _hasChanged=true;
            _hasChangedObserverable.sendValue(_value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearChangedState() {
        _hasChanged=false;
    }
//endregion
    //region observers
    @Override
    public void addChangeObserver(Observer observer) {
        _hasChangedObserverable.addObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeChangeObserver(Observer observer) {
        _hasChangedObserverable.deleteObserver(observer);
    }
    //endregion
    //endregion
}
```

and here is an Sample of Code what I mean:

```
DataField dataField = new DataField<Integer>(5);
dataField.setValue(true); // This can be prevented because of checking Class

DataField dataField = new DataField<String>(null);
dataField.setValue(5); // This can not be prevented because of NullPointer Exception
```

I found some Solutions like this [How to keep generic type of nested generics with class tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231043/how-to-keep-generic-type-of-nested-generics-with-class-tokens)
but I don't like to overgive the Class two times
Another Idea of mine was to use a default(T) Function like C# to presetMy Value to an specific Type.

Thanks for help

Comment: `DataField dataField` declares a variable with a *raw* generic type. **Do not use *raw* generics**, since it totally disables the type-checking of generics. Correct syntax is: `DataField<Integer> dataField = new DataField<>(5);` or `var dataField = new DataField<>(5);` (Java 10+)

Comment: So you mean you are getting `IllegalValueException` for first statement and `NullPointerException` for second?

Comment: Switch on warnings in your compiler and take notice of them. It's incredible how much warnings are ignored.

Comment: The Plan is to save a Set of Different DataFields in an HashMap
like: 
Username,DataField<String>
DateOfBirth,DataField<LocalDate>,
Size,DataField<Integer>, ...

Comment: Is their an Datatype related null or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a seconde Construtor and a Class Field.

```
public DataField(T val) throws IllegalValueException {
        if(val==null) throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Class type couldn't be resolved from null");
        _value =val;
        _class=val.getClass();
        _hasChanged=false;
        _hasChangedObserverable=new ChildObserable<>();
    }
    public DataField(T val,Class<T> classType) throws IllegalValueException {
        if(val!=null &&  val.getClass()!=classType) throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Type of val and classType are Different");
        _class=classType;
        _value=val;
        _hasChanged=false;
        _hasChangedObserverable=new ChildObserable<>();
    }


@Override
    public void setValue(T value) throws IllegalValueException {
        if(_class!= value.getClass()) throw new IllegalValueException();
        if(value!=_value) {
            _value = value;
            _hasChanged=true;
            _hasChangedObserverable.sendValue(_value);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help